# return an image in vlookup or index match, or using indirect

Tags: excel, image, dynamic

I want to be able to do a sports bracket like a NCAA bracket with team logos based on the team name.

I found this: computergaga.com/blog/create-a-picture-lookup-in-excel

But as I see it I would have to hard code a variable for each team. I might as well just cut and paste the correct logo.  I am hoping there is a much more efficient way.

Basically I want if I enter SHS B2, B1 can have the SHS Logo but and then I can replicate that several times.

Any ideas? I thought indirect might work, but it doesn't seem to work on images. I would attach a file showing what I did with this, but I don't know how.

Comment: Did you try using INDEX/MATCH as that link shows?

Comment: yes, but all that is doing is hard coding it to a cell. I don't see an advantage to over cutting and pasting doing it that way. I want something more dynamic.